# How to reference a hash of array of hashes in order to compare values

Tags: arrays, perl, hashmap, perl-data-structures

I have the following data structure:

```
my %hash = (
    'hsa_circ_0024017|chr11:93463035-93463135+|NM_033395|KIAA1731  FORWARD' => [ 
        { 
          'energy' => '-4.3', 
          'spacer' => 'AGGCACC', 
          'end' => '97', 
          'start' => '81' 
        } 
    ],
    'hsa_circ_0067224|chr3:128345575-128345675-|NM_002950|RPN1  FORWARD' => [ 
        { 
          'energy' => '-4.4', 
          'spacer' => 'CAGT', 
          'end' => '17', 
          'start' => '6' 
        }, 
        { 
          'energy' => '-4.1', 
          'spacer' => 'GTT', 
          'end' => '51', 
          'start' => '26' 
        }, 
        { 
          'energy' => '-4.1', 
          'spacer' => 'TTG', 
          'end' => '53', 
          'start' => '28' 
        } 
    ],
    ...
);
```

How do I access the contents of my hash to be able to compare the contents within a loop?

For each parent hash (hsa_circ...) I want to compare the child hashes (spacers) together. Forgive me I'm struggling to word this right. This is a small sample of the data of course. My goal, in brief, is to detect the arrays of hashes which have the same spacer and if they do have the same spacer then I want to then choose the array of hashes which has the **lowest** energy score.

Comment: In the future, pleas use `Dumper(\%hash)` instead of `Dumper(%hash)`

Comment: What does any of "*I would like to compare the value of the spacer hashes within the $VAR125/$VAR126 hash with each other*" mean? Hashes don't have "a value", and what result do you want?

Comment: e.g. I would like to compare the spacers: **CAGT**,**GTT** and **TTG** with each other to see if they are the same. And then apply some if statements as I do so.

Comment: Did you forget about `AGGCACC`, or do you just want to compare the hashes of one top-level hash element at a time? What result do you want? (If there's all the same? The number of different values? The different values? something else?)

Comment: Yeah, for each daddy hash **(hsa_circ...)** I want to compare the baby hashes  **(spacers)** together.
Forgive me I'm struggling to word this right.
This is a small sample of the data of course. My goal, in brief, is to detect the arrays of hashes which have the same spacer and if they do have the same spacer then I want to then choose the array of hashes which has the highest energy score.

Comment: Okay, so take the second array of hashes as an example. I would like to compare those multiple spacers with each other. In the example, none of them are equal to each other, but in my data, there are numerous cases of equal spacers and I would like to detect them and then filter out the one spacer that has the highest energy score.

Comment: Alright.  What do you mean by "_filter out_"  -- remove all other hashrefs in that array?  Or just retrieve something (print or store)?

Comment: Remove all other hashrefs in that array.
Apologies for my misuse of terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: there may be groups of hashrefs in each arrayref with the equal *spacer* value. In each such group the hashref with the lowest *energy* value
need be identified, to replace that group.

Most work is done in `partition_equal()`, which identifies hashref groups with equal spacers

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw(reduce);
use Data::Dump qq(dd);

# Test data: two groups of equal-spacer hashrefs, in the first array only
my %hash = (  
    kA => [
        { 'energy' => -4.3, 'spacer' => 'AGGCACC' },
        { 'energy' => -2.3, 'spacer' => 'AGGCACC' },
        { 'energy' => -3.3, 'spacer' => 'CAGT' },
        { 'energy' => -1.5, 'spacer' => 'GTT' },
        { 'energy' => -2.5, 'spacer' => 'GTT' },
    ],
    kB => [
        { 'energy' => -4.4, 'spacer' => 'CAGT' },
        { 'energy' => -4.1, 'spacer' => 'GTT' },
        { 'energy' => -4.1, 'spacer' => 'TTG' },
    ],
);
#dd \%hash;

for my $key (keys %hash) {
    my ($spv, $unique) = partition_equal($hash{$key});
    next if not $spv;
    # Extract minimum-energy hashref from each group and add to arrayref
    # $unique, so that it can eventually overwrite this key's arrayref
    foreach my $spacer (keys %$spv) {
        my $hr_min = reduce { 
            $a->{energy} < $b->{energy} ? $a : $b 
        } @{$spv->{$spacer}};
        push @$unique, $hr_min;
    }
    # new: unique + lowest-energy ones for each equal-spacer group   
    $hash{$key} = $unique  if keys %$spv;
}    
dd \%hash;

# Sort array and compare neighbouring elements (hashrefs) 
sub partition_equal {
    my $ra = shift;
    my @sr = sort { $a->{spacer} cmp $b->{spacer} } @$ra;

    # %spv:    spacer value => [ hashrefs with it ], ...
    # @unique: hasrefs with unique spacer values    
    my (%spv, @unique);

    # Process first and last separately, to not have to test for them
    ($sr[0]{spacer} eq $sr[1]{spacer})
        ? push @{$spv{$sr[0]{spacer}}}, $sr[0]
        : push @unique, $sr[0];
    for my $i (1..$#sr-1) {
        if ($sr[$i]{spacer} eq $sr[$i-1]{spacer}  or 
            $sr[$i]{spacer} eq $sr[$i+1]{spacer}) 
        {
            push @{$spv{$sr[$i]{spacer}}}, $sr[$i]
        }
        else { push @unique, $sr[$i] }
    }
    ($sr[-1]{spacer} eq $sr[-2]{spacer})
        ? push @{$spv{$sr[-1]{spacer}}}, $sr[-1]
        : push @unique, $sr[-1];

    return if not keys %spv;
    return \%spv, \@unique;
}
```

Output

```
kA => [
        { energy => -3.3, spacer => "CAGT" },
        { energy => -2.5, spacer => "GTT" },
        { energy => -4.3, spacer => "AGGCACC" },
      ],
kB => [
        { energy => -4.4, spacer => "CAGT" },
        { energy => -4.1, spacer => "GTT" },
        { energy => -4.1, spacer => "TTG" },
      ],
```

The order inside arrayrefs is not maintained; the new arrayref has first hashrefs with unique spacer values, then those with lowest-energy value (for each original group with same spacer-values).

The sub sorts input by spacer values, so that it can identify equal ones by simply iterating through the sorted array and comparing only neighbors. This should be reasonably efficient.

Comment: I've been trying to think of a way of doing this, but I'm struggling to see how to do it without actually going through all spacers, and comparing `spacer[0]` with `spacer[1]`, then with spacer[2] etc, with these comparisons inter-spliced with _if_ and _elsif_ statements detailing what to do if they are equal or not. I'm not sure, but somehow the comparisons need to occur without specifying the exact spacers, something like spacer[n], spacer[n+1], spacer[n+2] etc Otherwise you'd need to know before how many spacers to compare, I think.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking about that, I just didn't know if `reduce` could work on strings in the same way.It;s a neat function.

Comment: @MrKeystrokes  Yes, `reduce` is a very helful thingy.  Most of `List::Util` functions can be written very simply with it, for example.  It takes a list, and by pairwise comparison reduces it to one element, that compares "better" to all others (according to the chosen criterion). The `$a` and `$b` represent the pair of elements being compared.

Comment: @MrKeystrokes  The procedure you describe is possible; every element need be compared against all (with yet more to do). Rather picky.  The trick is: sort first. Then you just need to look at neighbors.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what data structure would you have adopted having seen the initial data layout, HoAoH or something else?

Comment: @MrKeystrokes  This data structure seems quite fine for it. That never crossed my mind as a problem. You have keys to a collection of hashrefs, rather logical I think. (When those get nested too deeply switching to a class may help. Not here, this is fine.)

Comment: Okie dokie :)
What is going on with: `my $ra = shift;` and its use in: `my @sr = sort { $a->{spacer} cmp $b->{spacer} } @$ra;` I know that `shift` is used to remove the first element from an array, but how is it functioning in this context.

Comment: Input for a sub is in `@_` array.  `shift` by default works with it (so is the same as `shift @_;`) and it takes an element off of the front of array, so `my $ra = shift;` is how we get our input.  (Or just assign, `my ($ra) = @_;`).  The input is arrayref.  Then I sort the hashrefs in it by the value of spacer in each.  Input for `sort` is an array so I dereference `$ra`, which is `@$ra`. Once we have the sorted hashrefs (by spacer value) it's easy to partition them into groups of equal.  Is this OK?

Comment: Yeah, I've read. That makes sense to me now. I am just slowly reading the code and referring to perldoc every now and then, much of it is new to me. Yeah, it's fine to remove that part. :)

Comment: @MrKeystrokes  I removed some of my comments which were by now outdated, or unneeded. (This may put some of yours in a limbo, check.) We should clean up a little.  Please let me know if questions pop up :)

Comment: I'll do the same. And yeah, I'll keep you updated as to any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$_=$hash{'hsa_circ_0024017|chr11:93463035-93463135+|NM_033395|KIAA1731  FORWARD'}->[0]{energy};

print  $_ ."\n";
```

so it's
$this{hash}->[array_ref]{hash]

Comment: Not sure if i understand the question... you can access a hash element by directly accessing it (as above) or doing  a loop through the hash keys

Answer (score 0):

```
for my $line (keys(%by_line)) {
   my $spacer_defs = $by_line{$line};
   ...
}
```

or

```
for my $spacer_defs (values(%by_line)) {
   ...
}
```

will get you (the reference to) the array of (references to) *spacer definitions* for each line in turn. Then, you can edit that array as follows:

```
   my %uniq_spacer_defs;
   for my $spacer_def (@$spacer_defs) {
      my $spacer = $spacer_def->{spacer};
      $uniq_spacer_defs{$spacer} = $spacer_defs
         if !$uniq_spacer_defs{$spacer}
         || $uniq_spacer_defs{$spacer}{energy} < $spacer_def->{energy};
   }

   @$spacer_defs = values(%uniq_spacer_defs);
```

---

Notes:

- The order of the "spacer definitions" may change. If that's a problem, replace

  ```
  @$spacer_defs = values(%uniq_spacer_defs);
  ```

  with

  ```
  @$spacer_defs = grep { $uniq_spacer_defs{$_->{spacer}} == $_ } @$spacer_defs;
  ```
- In case of two spacer definitions with the same spacer and the same energy, the first one encountered is kept.