# Perl sort hash of hashes by the third-level key and compare it

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

My data structure is

```
my %hash = (
    firstkey  => { 
                secondkey => {
                            2 => ['9','2'],
                            1 => ['3','4'],
                            3 => ['8','2']
                }
            }
);

print Dumper \%hash;
```

I want to sort the hash by the thirdly key. i.e. `1`, `2` and `3` in this case
and then compare the second element (`index[1]`) in the array. If they are the same, and then print it out.

Expected Sorted Hash:

```
my %hash = (
    firstkey  => { 
                secondkey => {
                            1 => ['3','4'],
                            2 => ['9','2'],
                            3 => ['8','2']
                }
            }
);

print Dumper \%hash;
```

After sort the hash, we compare the `index[1]` of the 1st array`[3,4]` with the 2nd array`[9,2]`.
`4` is not equal to `2`, so we are not going to print anything.

Then, we compare the `index[1]` of the 2nd array`[9,2]` with the 3rd array`[4,2]`.
`2` is equal to `2`, then we are going to print all the content of it

`firstkey, secondkey, 3, [8,2]`

we only need to compare the adjacent array.

I read a lot of solutions about sorting the hash, but I couldn't find one solution that really reorders it Is it any way to reorder the hash by the key and construct a hash with the new order in Perl? 
Or we can only sort the hash by using the for loop and compare it in the for loop?

Comment: You cannot "_sort hash_" -- they are intrinsically unordered.  But you _can_ get a sorted list of keys, using `sort` on the list of hash's keys with any criteria you wish.  Then you have an _ordered_ list of keys to iterate though so you can use your hash in a "sorted manner." See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45338396/4653379) for sorting a similar hash, or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45928281/4653379) for a bit more involved sort with some comments.  There is a lot more out there.

Comment: @zdim Thanks for your suggestions. I am trying that.

Comment: While the above comment is in general fine and needed, and worth following through, it may not help in this problem (and so could be misleading) -- I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cannot have a "sorted hash" – they are intrinsically unordered data structures (see [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)). The randomizaton of the initial seed and hash traversal are even [enhanced for security purposes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks).

But we can sort the list of hash keys as needed. Then we have an ordered list to iterate over and thus can process the hash in a "sorted manner."

The keys to sort by here are at a deeper level, so iterate over the upper (two) levels to get to them.  Then it's a straightforward sort and test

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my %hash = ( 
    firstkey1 => { 
        secondkey1 => { 
            2 => [9, 2], 1 => [3, 4], 3 => [8, 2]  
        }   
    }   
);

foreach my $k1 (keys %hash) 
{
    foreach my $k2 (keys %{$hash{$k1}}) 
    {   
        # Relieve syntax below
        my $hr = $hash{$k1}{$k2};

        my @sr_k3 = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{$hr};

        foreach my $i (1..$#sr_k3)
        {
            if ( $hr->{$sr_k3[$i]}[1] == $hr->{$sr_k3[$i-1]}[1] )
            {
                say "$k1, $k2, $sr_k3[$i], ", 
                    '[', join(',', @{$hr->{$sr_k3[$i]}}), ']';
            }
        }   
        #say "@{$hash{$k1}{$k2}{$_}}" for keys %{$hash{$k1}{$k2}};
    }   
}
```

A few notes

- Sorted keys are iterated over *starting with the second one* due to the comparison criterion
- Hashref is copied at the second level only for convenience, to relieve the messy syntax
- When complex data structures get too unwieldy it may be time to use a class instead

This works for any number of keys in both levels (only one key is shown for each level).

Comment: Pretty simple and straightforward solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, you won't be able to dictate the order of the hash. Here's a way to map it to something you can sort and do the comparison you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ( firstkey => {
                secondkey => {
                    2 => [9,2],
                    1 => [3,4],
                    3 => [8,2],
                }
            }
        );


#obtain an array of two-element array refs, whose contents are the keys
#for the "secondkey" hash and the corresponding value, respectively

my @arr = map { [ $_, $hash{firstkey}->{secondkey}->{$_} ] }
          keys %{$hash{firstkey}->{secondkey}};

#sort on the aforementioned key

my @sorted = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @arr;

#obtain an array of array refs, whose contents are a pair of adjacent 
#elements from the @sorted array

my @ordered_pairs = map { [ $sorted[$_], $sorted[$_+1] ] }
                    (0 .. (scalar @sorted - 2));

#compare the elements in question, and do something if there's a match

for (@ordered_pairs) {
    if ($_->[0][1][1] == $_->[1][1][1]) {
        print Dumper $_->[1];
    }
}
```